# Joining _JourneyActivity and _Sent Data Views in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql, automationstudio, data-views

Did anyone here manage to successfully join the data from `_JourneyActivity` and `_Sent` data views? The documentation says that they can be joined on `_JourneyActivity.JourneyActivityObjectID = _Sent.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID`. But I'm facing the following issue:

There is a journey that has quite a lot of entries.
Majority of contacts inside the journey received email communications.
However, when I join the data from `_Sent` with the data from `_JourneyActivity` and applying the filter on the JourneyID of that specific Journey - I get 0 records. I double checked and realized that there is simply no match between `JourneyActivityObjectID` and `TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID` for that Journey.

Comment: Hi @Orkhan, Welcome to SFSE! Can you please paste the code for SQL which you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible to join those data views. Just as a reminder: data views keep data only for 6 months.

For the subscribers that didn't receive the communication, check if they are valid subscribers so a send is theoretically possible. If so, also join the data JourneyActivity view with the Bounce view to see it there are any bounces.

To join check with the JourneyID, you need an additional join between JourneyActivity and Journey data views.

To find sends for a specific journey your SQL could look like this:

```sql
SELECT
    s.JobID,
    s.ListID,
    s.BatchID,
    s.SubscriberKey,
    s.EventDate,
    s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
FROM
    _sent s
JOIN
    _JourneyActivity ja
ON
    s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
JOIN
    _Journey j
ON
    ja.VersionID = j.VersionID
WHERE
    j.JourneyID = 'YOUR JOURNEY ID'
```

Also make sure to check out the ER-diagram linked below, as it makes building these queries pretty easy.

**Helpful resources:**

- [Entity-Relationship diagram for Data Views in Salesforce Marketing Cloud](https://markus.codes/2020/02/28/salesforce-marketing-cloud-data-views-entity-relationship-diagram)
- [Data Views documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5)

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks for you feedback. 

This is exactly what I'm using at the moment. However, the problem is that there is no match between s.TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID and therefore I'm getting 0 records. If I query the _JourneyActivity data view of the specific journey to find all its JourneyActivityObjectID, and then use these values to search for their occurence in TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID of the _Sent data view - I don't find anything.

Comment: And this is weird to me, because a lot of emails were sent in that journey and how comes that there is no match between _Sent.TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID and _JourneyActivity.JourneyActivityObjectID ?

Comment: Did you test with your own email address is the email is definitely sent and delivered? What does the tracking of that send in the user interface show? If you know one subscriber you could review the subscriber's data in the sent view and further investigate.

Answer (score 1):

it's not TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID,
it's     TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID

I used with _Bounce Data View and it worked:

...
from
_Bounce b
join
_JourneyActivity ja
on
b.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
join
_Journey j
on
ja.VersionID = j.VersionID
...